# App installation failed during run App in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift2

[image]

I upgrade my xcode after update in xcode_8 I have faced many issues like app not running in simulator as well as some time not run in device .It gives me an error **App installation failed.An unknown error has occoured.** Out of five three time run on device and 2 time not run and provisioning profile is correct because app run in device.
In simulator it gives an exception of slidemenu franework.
Code totally update with `xcode_8` and `swift 2.3.`

Comment: Delete the application with same bundle identifier in your iPad, if any.

Comment: There is no any app in ipad.Its new  bundle Id.

Comment: check build setting set provision profile to Automatic

Comment: @Noman I set autometic and it works for me.

Comment: Pease Can any one help ?

Comment: @HarshRajput, Can you described more about App functionality bcs Xcode contains many update regarding security, app compatibility and Also vefied certificate and app in iTunes. For Ex, is you access photo album then u must be specified app will access photo album in info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, described above, the only thing that fixed this was to restart my Mac, it then started working again.

Comment: Vote down is meant for different purposes, in this case that's the only solution that worked. I've tried everything - deleted the app, recreated the provisioning profile, restarted the device, restarted XCode, rebuilt and all. Restarting my Mac was the only thing that helped. Leave this here for other users to try.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the derived data, then run again.

Comment: Very short answers are automatically flagged as low quality. If you could take a few moments to explain answers more fully you'll save time for reviewers, avoid having your answer deleted, and (most importantly) provide a better answer for the OP and future readers.